# Differentiate questions loading from database by color coding in MVC

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am loading all the questions into model and then to db.

I am having a problem in color coding the questions.
I have a table in database where i am getting all the questions from.

this is the method i am using

```
  public List<QuestionAnswerModel> GetQuestionsbyAppId(int appId, string purpose = "XXX")
        {
            using (var context = new someEntities())
            {
                var data = (from q in context.Questions
                            join aq in context.Application_Question_Mapping.Where(a => a.ApplicationId == appId) on q.QuestionId equals aq.QuestionId into answer
                            from an in answer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where q.Purpose == purpose
                            select new QuestionAnswerModel
                            {
                                QuestionId = q.QuestionId,
                                QuestionText = q.QuestionText,
                                SelectedAnswer = an == null ? String.Empty : an.Answer,
                                QuestionOptions = q.QuestionOptions,
                                Comments = (an == null) ? string.Empty : an.Comments,
                                AnsweredBy = an == null ? null : an.AnsweredBy,
                                AnswerDateTime = an == null ? null : an.AnsweredTime,
                            }).ToList();

                return data;
            }
        }
```

and in HTML i am displaying questions as

```
 @foreach (var question in Model)
    {
        <div class="whiteContainer pad-10 pull-left col-lg-15" style="width: 95%; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 3px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="@question.QuestionId" name="QuestionId" id="QuestionId" />
                <label class="label-reports">@question.QuestionText</label>
                <br>
                @foreach (var ans in question.QuestionOptions.Split('|'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(question.SelectedAnswer) && ans == question.SelectedAnswer)
                    {
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" @((ViewBag.UserId != null && ViewBag.UserId == question.AnsweredBy) || (question.AnsweredBy == null) ? "" : "disabled") checked="checked" name="@string.Format("inlineRadioOptions-{0}", question.QuestionId)" id="@string.Format("{0}{1}", question.QuestionId, question.SelectedAnswer)" value="@ans"> @ans
                        </label>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" @((ViewBag.UserId != null && ViewBag.UserId == question.AnsweredBy) || (question.AnsweredBy == null) ? "" : "disabled") name="@string.Format("inlineRadioOptions-{0}", question.QuestionId)" id="@string.Format("{0}{1}", question.QuestionId, question.SelectedAnswer)" value="@ans"> @ans
                        </label>
                    }
                }
                <br />
                <label class="label-reports" >Comments</label>
                <input @((ViewBag.UserId != null && ViewBag.UserId == question.AnsweredBy) || (question.AnsweredBy == null) ? "" : "disabled") maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 900px !important" for="comments" value="@question.Comments" />
            </div>

        </div>
    }
```

By this i am able to get all the questions now the issue is i have to color code the some of the questions (say 1st question and 10 th question)

can anyone please suggest a method to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the determining factor in color coding? You can either put a property on the `QuestionAnswerModel` object and place that as the color of the div in your loop, or you can do a simple if statement in your view on the condition that determines which color it should be.

Comment: I want the color of all questions from 2-8 to be red

Comment: why 9 is there is a scenario here by which i should make the particular question display in different color

Comment: So if you have 16 questions, and they're all the *exact same question*, you still want questions 2-8 to be red?

Comment: No they are not all same questions they differ, there are only particular questions in between them where i need to color code as they need to be displayed in different color as they are more important than others

Comment: That's a hypothetical question. You're getting close to giving us an valid explanation.

Comment: "why 9 is there is a scenario here by which i should make the particular question display in different color" - Exactly, so *what* is that scenario that makes it a different color? "No they are not all same questions they differ, there are only particular questions in between them where i need to color code as they need to be displayed in different color as they are more important than others" - Again, *what* makes that question more important?

Comment: Actually there is no determining factor, all the questions that are loading have different priorities some of them have to highlighted as they have to be answered, I want those questions to be displayed in different color so that user understands that they are mandatory or high priority.

Comment: user should answer those highlighted questions, that makes them more important

Comment: There has to be a determining factor. You just said the questions have different priorities. I do not see a `Priority` property on your model. Let me ask this a different way. How do *you* as the developer know which questions have higher priorities? Meaning, how do you know which ones you want to highlight?

Comment: Its a business requirement they provided me to display some questions with different color, there are no flags or any checks in the program to determine the priority,I tried to get all the questions from database but i couldn't make some of them appear in different color. I am sorry if i am being too dumb to understand your question

Comment: You have 10 questions. Some have to be a different color. How do you know which questions are to be a different color? Does the business requirement say, "randomly pick 2 questions and make them a different color?" or is the requirement "top 2 questions should be a different color?", etc. How do you as the programmer know which questions are to be made a different color? I'm not sure I can be any more clear on my question.

Comment: It was similar to that say they want top 5 questions to be red color and next 5 to be blue color, i have a questionid coming from db table based on them i want to color it

Comment: @Alpha5 did the answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is confusion on what determines if a question is a different color or not. However, according to OP:

"It was similar to that say they want top 5 questions to be red color and next 5 to be blue color, i have a `questionid` coming from db table based on them i want to color it"

With that in mind, you can simply put an `if` statement in your Razor to determine the color.

```
@if (question.questionId <= 5)
{
    <div class="redContainer pad-10 pull-left col-lg-15" style="width: 95%; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 3px">
}
else
{
    <div class="blueContainer pad-10 pull-left col-lg-15" style="width: 95%; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 3px">
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i did exactly. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to the person who gave you your specification and tell them that there needs to be another property in the question model that can be used to determine the colour.

If you colour question 4, 5 and 6 red, what happens when someone inserts a new question above or between them in the data? You have to change code! Code that should be done, forgotten and never need changing again!